# Utility to download and rename a bunch of files?

Tags: windows, software-rec, download, rename

[This Bash script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1099378) is fine to download just a few files, but I need to download over a hundred of them. [VisualWGet](http://khomsanph.net/apps/visualwget) is able to download a file of files, but is unable to rename them.

Does someone know of a Windows utility that would take a two-column text list where column 1 would contain the full URL to the file, and column 2 would contain the name to be used for renaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Download Accelerator Plus (DAP) to do both the downloading and renaming.

You just need to create a DAP list, import it into the app, select the folder you want the files saved in then let it do the work.

To create a DAP list, just open a text editor and enter the following for each file you wanna download:

```
<filelist_index><fileinfo>
    <filename>FILENAME.EXT</filename>
    <url>FULL_URL_TO_FILE</url>
</fileinfo></filelist_index>
```

Replace FILENAME.EXT with the filename you want (don't forget the file EXTENSION). Just use MS Excel to consolidate the code then copy-paste them to a text file and save it as a XXX.DAP file. Here's a sample spreadsheet: http://ge.tt/6sO1B2g

Answer (score 1):

### Or, using windows powershell...

```
$folder = "D:\Output\"
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
$web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$web.Headers.Add("user-agent", $userAgent)
$input = "D:\todownload.txt"
$delimit = " "

Get-Content $input |
    Foreach-Object { 
        $line = $_.split($delimit);
        $destination_file = ([io.path]::getfilename($line[1]))
        "[" + $destination_file  + "]" + "Downloading " + $line[0]
        try {
            $target = join-path $folder $destination_file
            $web.DownloadFile($line[0], $target)
        } catch {
            $_.Exception.Message + ": " + $destination_file
            add-content (join-path $folder ("downloader" + ".log")) ("[" + $destination_file + "] " + $_.Exception.Message)
            add-content (join-path $folder ("downloader" + ".retry")) ($line -join " ")
        }
    }
```

The input file (todownload.txt) is in the format:

```
http://path.to.download.com/file.jpg 0001_NewFileName_file.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a shot to the Firefox extension [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). It can download multiple links from a page, you can filter the download list and also apply a rename pattern.

Comment: Thanks but I need to turn eg. "419FD4E354AF7CA75D06" into "main.c", etc. so a simple rename pattern won't do.

Comment: I see. In that case you can (for example) write an extremely simple Perl script. There are two different Perl distribution on windows available. It would slurp the mapping file and then apply it on a directory.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to write a web crawler. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> `perl -MLWP::Simple -n -e '($u,$n)=split;getstore($u,$n)' filenames.txt`

(Tested OK)

where filenames.txt contains something like

```
http://foo.com/a/b?parm=x   this.dat
http://bar.org//d/e/f.html  that.html
```

The same script in longer form

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

open my $fh, '<', "filenames.txt" or die "can't read filenames.txt because $!\n";
while () {
  my ($url, $newname) = split;
  getstore($url, $newname);
}
```

(Untested)